# List has no rows for assignment to SObject test class

Tags: unit-test

Getting this error on line controller.Save();

I haven't written a test class in a long time and I'm a bit rusty.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
@isTest 
private class MultiAdTest{
static testMethod void MultiAdTest_test() {

       Account testAccount = new Account(
        Name = 'Test Account'
    );
    
    insert testAccount;
    List<Support_Subscription__c> newsub = new List<Support_Subscription__c>();
Support_Subscription__c sub = new Support_Subscription__c(
                                    Dealer_Name__c = testAccount.Id,
                                    Subscription_Start_Date__c = Date.today(),
                                    of_Months__c = 12,
                                    Date_Received__c = Date.today(),
                                    Date_Received_Executed__c = Date.today(),
                                    Subscription_Status__c = 'Active',
                                    Dealer_Sales_Person__c = 'Mike Gray',
                                    Software_End_User_Agreement_Version_Date__c = Date.today());
       Test.startTest();
        insert sub;
        newsub.add(sub);
        
//create a license Record
        Subscription_Assets__c asset = new Subscription_Assets__c(
                                    Support_Subscription__c = sub.Id);
        insert asset;
       
          Test.stopTest(); 

ApexPages.StandardController con2 = new ApexPages.StandardController(asset);
MultiAd controller = new MultiAd(con2);
controller.Save();

PageReference testPage = Page.CW_Subscription_Purchase_Agreement;
Test.setCurrentPage(testPage);
```

```
/*
Class/Method Name: MultiAd
Description: Created Subscription Assets related to Support Subscription
Author/Date: Staci Gilmore 5/27/2020
*/
public with sharing class MultiAd { 
private final Subscription_Assets__c ln; 
Public string ss;
public List<AccountWrapper> wrappers{get;set;}
private Integer nextIdent=0;

public MultiAd(ApexPages.StandardController controller) { 

ss = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');

wrappers=new List<AccountWrapper>();
for(Integer idx=0; idx<1; idx++)
{
    wrappers.add(new AccountWrapper(nextIdent++));
}} 

public List<Subscription_Assets__c> addlic {get; set;} 
public PageReference Save()
{
    List<Subscription_Assets__c> addlic=new List<Subscription_Assets__c>();
    Support_Subscription__c ssid = [select id, Name, RecordTypeID from Support_Subscription__c where id=:ss];
    for(AccountWrapper wrap:wrappers)
    {
       Subscription_Assets__c lic =wrap.asset;
       lic.Support_Subscription__c = ssid.id;
       addlic.add(lic);
    }
        
    insert addlic;

    PageReference pageRef = ApexPages.currentPage();
    pageRef.setRedirect(true);
    return pageRef;  
}

public class AccountWrapper
{
    public Subscription_Assets__c asset{get; private set;}
    public Integer ident{get; private set;}
        
    public AccountWrapper(Integer inIdent)
    {
        ident=inIdent;
        asset=new Subscription_Assets__c();
            
    }
}         
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MultiAd` sources its `ss` instance variable, which defines the query filter for

```
[select id, Name, RecordTypeID from Support_Subscription__c where id=:ss];
```

from the current page parameters, but your unit test class does not set the `id` parameter, i.e., `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id', <desired id>);`

Alternately, you could simply have your extension controller get its record id directly from the standard controller via `getRecord()`.